# Time interval not resetting, however same code runs fine on another site

Tags: javascript, web

My friend has given me files of his website to clone and make my own version, everything works as intended except for this time interval function. It works perfectly fine on my friends website, however on mine I found the countdown goes to zero, refreshes the page and doesn't reset, causing the page to reload constantly

```
var x = setInterval(function() {
var thing = parseInt($('#quest_reset').val());
thing = thing * 1000;
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = thing - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds
  if (distance < 0) {
      console.log(distance)
    clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = 0
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = 0
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = 0

        location.reload();
  }
}, 1000);
```

The original value of `thing` is `1628380822`, which would mean the value of `#quest_reset` would also be `1628380822` I found the value of `now` is much larger than `thing`
How come this works fine on my friends website but not on mine?

Comment: How does `thing` get to be 1628380822 if it is a multiple of 1000? And what is the value of `#quest_reset` and how does it get there. Please clarify the problem in sufficient detail for readers to reproduce what's going wrong. For more information please feel free to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, should've worded it better. I meant the original value of thing is 1628380822, which would mean the value of #quest_reset is also 1628380822

Comment: Yes, it would mean that. So what is the problem? Your code does not reveal how `#quest_rest` got its value, let be that it should have any relation with `now`

Comment: `#quest_rest` is getting it the value `1628380822` from a database using this line
`$reset = \App\Models\Quests::where('id', 1)->first();`
The problem is when the timer counts down to zero it does not restart the timer, causing the page to constantly reload.
The solution I am looking is for the timer to reset when it counts down to zero.

Comment: when `thing` describes a timestamp in the past (as your timestamp does) the distance will always be less than `0` thus your page will always reload ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you code is fine, but here is my version. Instead of all the calculations you can use the Date object.

Here I define a future date by creating a new date and add 20 seconds to it. This is the timestamp that you compare against. This could also be a fixed number -- like the `thing` that you refer to.

In the function `checktime` the ´diffdate´ is the difference between the future date and now. If diff is less then 0 diffdate is set to 0, the interval is cleared and you can then reload or whatever. As the last thing (instead of repeating the same code) in the function the hour, minutes and seconds are set in the HTML elements.

All timestamps in the browser will start at Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT. Try to `console.log(new Date(0))`. Your `thing` is a number of milliseconds -- probably the difference or a period defined by something. That is why `thing` is mush smaller than `new Date().getTime()` because that is the number of milliseconds from Jan 01 1970 and until now.

```js
var h = document.getElementById("hours");
var m = document.getElementById("minutes");
var s = document.getElementById("seconds");

var futuredate = new Date();
futuredate.setSeconds(futuredate.getSeconds() + 20);

const checktime = function() {
  let now = new Date();
  let diffdate = new Date(futuredate - now);
  let zero = new Date(0);
  if (diffdate.getTime() < 0) {
    diffdate = new Date(0);
    clearInterval(x);
    console.log('reload!');
  }
  h.innerText = diffdate.getHours() - zero.getHours();
  m.innerText = diffdate.getMinutes() - zero.getMinutes();
  s.innerText = diffdate.getSeconds() - zero.getSeconds();
};

var x = setInterval(checktime, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="hours"></span>
  <span id="minutes"></span>
  <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```